# specifying three cluster groups, but dendrogram clusters into four

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram, dendextend

I'm having a frustrating problem that I can't reproduce (I wish I could). I've generated dendrograms with three ecological datasets, using the same code but unique objects for each. Each leaf in the dendrograms is a survey plot, with species presence/abundance driving the clustering.

I cut the dendrogram into 3 groups, and color code each group. This works for fine for all three datasets when clustering using Euclidean distance, and for two of my datasets when using Bray-Curtis distance. However: the third dataset clusters two leaves when using Bray-Curtis, and forces the color code to recycle, creating k = 4 groups despite specifying k = 3.

My question is: why would two leaves (plots) be forced into their own 'cluster,' and force the dendrogram to have 4 clusters when I've specified k = 3 groups?

I've pasted below an example of the code, and images of the "correct" and "wrong" dendrograms.
Curious if anyone has any troubleshooting suggestions, since I can't offer code that reproduces this error. TIA.

I've tried:

- removing the custom color value (no effect, still get 4 clusters when k = 3).
- adding a cutree argument to the 'dend' object, but this produces error 'Error in stats::cutree(tree, k = k, h = h, ...) :
  the 'height' component of 'tree' is not sorted (increasingly)'

Example code (same format with unique objects used for each dendrogram figure). Please access csv from https://drive.google.com/file/d/12eXIXVuHTu4BLGxcGu18bqhT85ZOHkNW/view?usp=sharing. See file clusterdata.csv for the troublesome dataset. Colnames are species; rows are plot ID; values are cover class bins (0 = absent, 1 = < 25%, 2 = 25-50%, etc.)

```
#library(dendextend)
d <- read.csv("clusterdata.csv")

dend <- d %>% 
vegdist(method = "bray") %>% 
hclust(method = "ward.D") %>% 
# cutree(h = 3) %>% 
as.dendrogram()

mycol <- c("#009E73", "#0072B2", "#E69F00")

dend.plot <-  as.dendrogram(dend) %>%
   set("branches_lwd", 2) %>% # Branches line width
   set("branches_k_color", mycol, k = 3) %>% # Color branches by groups
   set("labels_cex", 0.5) # Change label size
plot(dend.plot, ylab = "Bray-Curtis Distance", main = "why would clusters be different?")
```

[image: "correct" dendrogram - cut & color coded at three highest levels]
[image: "wrong" dendrogram - why are the two orange leaves their own cluster?!?]

Comment: Maybe try the factoextra package? `fviz_dend(dend.plot, k=3, color_labels_by_k=T)` and see if you get the same result?

Comment: Thanks, @alexrai93 for your thought! Unfortunately, no luck - same type of error: " Length of color vector was shorter than the number of clusters - color vector was recycled
Warning: `guides(<scale> = FALSE)` is deprecated. Please use `guides(<scale> = "none")` instead.

Comment: Hey,Could you please use dput(d) so to make the example fully reproducible? This would allow me (or others) to try and debug.

Comment: Thanks, @TalGalili - I edited my post to include a link to the dataset that's giving me issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution in the post below that involves an intermediate step rounding the height component to get around the height differences being too small or negative.

```
dend <- d %>% 
vegdist(method = "bray") %>% 
hclust(method = "ward.D")
dend$height <- round(dend$height, 6)
dend <- as.dendrogram(dend)
```

It worked fine with average linkage but with Ward some distances are extremely small. You'll notice the values are a lot more reasonable after rounding if you run this:

```
dend <- d %>% 
vegdist(method = "bray") %>% 
hclust(method = "ward.D")

dend$height
diff(round(dend$height,6))
```

[The 'height' component of 'tree' is not sorted Error in cutree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46749829/the-height-component-of-tree-is-not-sorted-error-in-cutree)

Also interesting discussion on Cross Validated on issues combining HC with Bray Distance: [HC With Bray Distance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233136/appropriateness-of-hierarchical-cluster-analysis-with-bray-curtis-dissimilarity)

Comment: Thanks @alexrai93! That fixed the color groupings for the clusters. Is there a way to view the rounded values with `dend$height` or `diff(round(dend$height, 6))`? When I try to run just those lines, I get `NULL` and `Error in round(d2019_bray$height, 6) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function`, respecively

Comment: My bad - you need to run those lines prior to calling as.dendogram() when it's still a cluster object - I edited the answer to include the prior lines required. No problem, glad it helped.